# Anaconda 4.3.1 Navigator can't open on macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Tags: python, anaconda, macos-sierra

Anaconda 4.3.1 can't open on macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Anaconda Navigator crashes upon launching it.

Please, help me to solve this problem

Tips for layman would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: Sure.  I tried it several times but failed

Comment: Please try to open Navigator from your terminal by typing "anaconda-navigator." Then share the traceback that occurs when it fails/crashes.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue with Mac OS 10.12.6. Solved by updating anaconda:

```
$conda update anaconda-navigator
$conda install navigator-updater
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open the navigator using 'sudo anaconda-navigator'

Comment: did you have the problems mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 0):

it seems the anaconda-navigator from the official website is not compatible with any version of Mac which is below v10.13. I tried on macOS Sierra 10.12.6, but it says -

"Referenced from: /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt5/../../../libQt5Core.5.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
in /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt5/../../../libQt5Core.5.dylib"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).